# Doing induction on recurrences correctly

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, induction

I have $$T(n)=T(n-1)+n^{2}$$
And I know, by drawing the recursion tree that this is $\Theta (n^{3})$
However, if I try claiming that it's $O(n^{2})$ through induction:
$$T(n)\le c(n-1)^{2}+n^{2}\le cn^{2}$$
which evaluates to
$$c\ge \frac{n^2}{2n-1}$$
Which makes $c>0$ for all $n>1$ and concludes that the recurrence is $O(n^{2})$ which is not correct.
So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that $c(n-1)^2 + n^2 = cn^2 - 2cn + c +n^2 \leq (c+1)n^2$, so the constant $c$ is in fact no constant, since it grows with every step.

So you get that when $n$ increases by 1, $c$ also does, so you have $O(n) \cdot n^2$, so $O(n^3)$.

Comment: So in cases like this we find Big-Oh for c and use that to deduce the Big-Oh for the original recurrenc, right?

Comment: You can think of it that way, but I think if you don't use the Master Theorem, then the best way is to unfold the recurrence or look at how it grows with each step. If you know that some recursive equation is $O(f)$, then you can try proving it the way you tried, but make sure that constants are actually constants.

Comment: Now I understand, so it can be a function in n, but has to be O(1). How about checking that the constant is positive, do we have to check that it's positive for all n greater than some n_nought?

Comment: Well, if we are talking Computer Science, then usually recursive relations describe the running time of an algorithm, and so they should be positive.
Saying that something can be a function in $n$ but be $O(1)$ is kinda pointless, because if something is $O(1)$, then it is a constant, like $3$, but the number $3$ can be called a function in any argument.